# REST PUT url conventions

Tags: rest, put

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to do an update using REST conventions. So far we have:

Update for a single item:

```
PUT
https://mydomain.com/dogs/{id}    accept: application/json, {dog}
```

Update for multiple items:

```
PUT
https://mydomain.com/dogs    accept: application/json, [{dog1}, {dog2}, ...]
```

I'm trying to figure out if convention also dictates (in addition to, or instead of what we have above) this for a single item:

```
PUT
https://mydomain.com/dogs    accept: application/json, {dog}
```

And then, followup question: say one element has a validation error when we update a collection. Does convention dictate that we return a 422 and reject the entire request? Or do we update the valid ones and return 4xx status code?

Comment: In your second example (the list), better to use POST. POST is the "append" verb, and you're appending two items to the list of dogs. PUT means "This is the whole collection of dogs!". ... The problem with the 3rd example is that you don't know what {id} the dog has! And it's not the representation of the dogs collection! So you're better off just using (1) or else using POST again in (3). POST is more common for create. ... How you return validation errors is totally up to you -- I don't know that there's a clear convention. I'd probably reject the whole thing IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

PUT is generally used for an update, but PUT does not mean update.  The basic idea behind PUT is that you are putting a resource at a specific location.  Your first code segment is accurate in that you are putting a new version of that resource at that location.

However, the following two requests do not uphold the semantics of PUT:

```
PUT
https://mydomain.com/dogs    accept: application/json, [{dog1}, {dog2}, ...]

PUT
https://mydomain.com/dogs    accept: application/json, {dog}
```

Generally, I would require those calling my API to execute multiple PUT requests, which can be done in parallel, to update multiple resources.  However, if it is necessary to update multiple resources at the same time, I would consider using a POST, such as:

```
POST
https://mydomain.com/dogs/update-many  accept: application/json, [{dog1}, ...]
```

As far as the error scenario, that would best be handled through documentation.  I feel that either rejecting the whole request and rolling back or returning a response that contains an identifier/success status for each entity that was sent would be valid, as long as the user is aware of the behavior.  Generally, I consider the response as being directly related to the request, and not to each item in the request; therefore, if any part of the request fails, I return an error code and explanation.  I feel it is simpler for the user to always expect a 2XX code when assuming any piece of the request had a lasting impact.